# Why do we do right shifting in Booths algorithm?

Tags: computer-architecture, multiplier

I know the working of booths algorithm.

Suppose we have multiplicand M = 01011

and multiplier Q = 01110

We can write Q as (2^4 - 2^1).

So multiplication reduces to 2^4(M) + 2(-M)

Now booths algorithm rules are:-

If Q = 0 and Q(-1)=0 then do arithmetic right shift.

If Q = 1 and Q(-1)=0 then do A-M and arithmetic right shift.

If Q = 0 and Q(-1)=1 then do A+M and arithmetic right shift.

If Q = 1 and Q(-1)=1 then do arithmetic right shift.

Here A is initialized to 00000 and Q(-1) is initialized to 0.

If we see the algorithm then in every step we do right shifting. But as per the calculation shown above which is 2^4(M) + 2(-M) we multiply by 16 and 2 which requires left shift.

So how is booths algorithm working with right shift ?

Answer (score 2):

Booth's recoding scheme can be thought of as follows. Instead of using the radix 4 **canonical digit set** \$\{0,1,2,3\}\$ for the multiplier, we **recode** the digits into new set \$\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}\$, which by the way is a redundant digit set but non-redundant can also be used. This is done simply because we do not like to multiply by 3 as it cannot be easily implemented in hardware. So, in your example $$Q = 0\ 11\ 10 = 1\ -1\ \ 2.$$ Then you can perform the multiplication as usual as you do in a radix 4 case.
Since we are only multiplying by \$\pm2\$ we only require a right shift for multiplication, and maybe a complementation if the multiplier digit is negative.

Answer (score 1):

In right-shifting the Accumulator, the least significant portion of the product is shifted into another register and is protected against modification as the Multiplicand is added to the Accumulator.

In right shifting the Multiplier's next least significant bit is loaded into a single-bit flipflow and made available for use in decisions about what path to take in the Booth Algorithm

Comment: I know the working of algorithm. I am not able to get the intuition of how right shifting the multiplicand is equivalent to left shift multiplication in booths. As to multiply by 2^4 or 2, we need to left shift by 4 or 1 bits.

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the Booth's algorithm hardware

[image]

We perform arithmatic right shifts, but the position of the adder circuit is exactly over AC. Thus if we right shift and add, it is equivalent to adding and performing a left shift (read this line carefully). Its better to visualize this or writing down.